# Continuity of the basis of the null space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, analysis

Consider a real $n\times n$ matrix $A(\alpha)$ continuously dependent of a real vector $\alpha$, i.e. a real matrix-valued continuous function $A: \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.

If the rank of $A(\alpha)$ is the same for every $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^m$, it is true that it is always possible to continuously choose a basis for the null space of $A(\alpha)$? 
That is, there exists a continuous matrix valued function $N(\alpha)$ such that its columns form a basis for $A(\alpha)$ for every $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^m$?

Thanks for any help!

**Update**

Just to add more context for this question, for the case that the rank of $A(\alpha)$ is different for some $\alpha$, there are many counterexamples. More information about the non-constant rank case can be seen in the following MO questions:

1. [Conditions for smooth dependence of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix on a set of parameters](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43124/conditions-for-smooth-dependence-of-the-eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors-of-a-matrix)
2. [How to find/define eigenvectors as a continuous function of matrix?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/116123/how-to-find-define-eigenvectors-as-a-continuous-function-of-matrix)

Comment: I have a feeling you can use the implicit function theorem here to get an idea of what might work.

Comment: If the rank$(A(\alpha))=r<n$, then the matrix  $A(\alpha)$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda=0$, and the corresponding eigenspace is Null$(A(\alpha)$. While the eigenvalues vary continuously with respect to $\alpha$, it is possible that eigenvectors behave in an unexpected way.

Comment: @xecafe, thanks for pointing this. I found some counter-examples when searching for the continuity of eigenvectors of a continuous matrices, but in all of those the discontinuity appears when the dimension of the null space varies. Do you know an explicit counter-example for the case that the dimension of the eigenspace is constant?

Comment: @shamisen I don't know  any example.  Maybe you could  find  some counter-examples in the book Matrix Perturbation Theory, by Stewart and Sun.

Comment: Locally, the answer is clearly yes. Globally, I don't know the answer, but it seems to be negative. See Byrd and Schnabel (1986), [*Continuity of the null space basis and constrained optimization*](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01589439), Mathematical Programming, 35(1): 32-41.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Locally, the answer is clearly yes. Let's consider $\alpha=0$. Suppose the common rank is $k$. By singular value decomposition or by left and right multiplications of (possibly different) permutation matrices, we may assume that the leading principal $k\times k$ submatrix of $A(0)$ is invertible. Since $A(\alpha)$ is continuous and has rank $k$ for every $\alpha$, it follows that in a neighbourhood of $\alpha=0$, we have
$$
A(\alpha)=\begin{bmatrix}X(\alpha)&X(\alpha)Y(\alpha)\\ Z(\alpha)&Z(\alpha)Y(\alpha)\end{bmatrix}
$$
for some continuous functions $X,Y,Z,W$, with $X(\alpha)$ being a $k\times k$ invertible matrix. So, if $e_1,\ldots,e_{n-k}$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb R^{n-k}$, then
$$
\left\{\begin{bmatrix}-Y(\alpha)e_1\\ e_1\end{bmatrix},\,\ldots,\,\begin{bmatrix}-Y(\alpha)e_{n-k}\\ e_{n-k}\end{bmatrix}\right\}
$$
is a basis of the null space of $A(\alpha)$ and it varies continuously with $\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Although I understood why you could take block (1,2) of $A(\alpha)$ as $X(\alpha)Y(\alpha)$, I didn't understand why you could take block (2,2) as $Z(\alpha)Y(\alpha)$... could you explain this step in your derivation? Thanks again :)

Comment: @shamisen $X(\alpha)$ is invertible. Therefore $\pmatrix{X(\alpha)\\ Z(\alpha)}$ has rank $k$. But $A(\alpha)$ has rank $k$ too. Therefore its last $n-k$ columns are linear combinations of its first $k$ columns. In other words, its last $n-k$ columns are $\pmatrix{X(\alpha)\\ Z(\alpha)}Y(\alpha)$ for some matrix $Y(\alpha)$. Since $A(\alpha)$ is continuous and $X(\alpha)$ is continuous and invertible, it follows that $Y(\alpha)$ is continuous too.

Comment: Thanks again for answering the question. I'm planning to write a paper that uses your proof as a lemma for another result.  Would you mind if I acknowledged you in the paper? :)

Comment: @shamisen You are welcome. To cite an MSE answer, you may read [this meta link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4259/do-i-cite-mathematics-stack-exchange-in-my-thesis-paper).