# Can we continuously choose vectors from kernels of resolvent like operator?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Suppose we have two matrices $A, B$ where $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ and $B \in \mathbb R^{n \times m}$. Further assume the rank of $[\lambda I - A, B]$ is $n$ for any $\lambda \in \mathbb C$ where $[\lambda I -A, B]$ denotes concatenating the columns.

I am wondering whether we can choose a continuous function $v\colon \mathbb C \to \mathbb C^{n+m}$ by $\lambda \mapsto v(\lambda)$ where $v(\lambda) \in \ker([\lambda I -A, B])$. We need $v$ not to be identically $0$.

Comment: What do you mean by "choose a continuous function"?  The kernel is non-trivial, so clearly such a (non-zero) exists.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: For each $\lambda$, yes, the kernel $\ker([\lambda I - A, B]$ is nontrivial and we can choose a vector $v$. This $v$ is dependent on $\lambda$. So for each $\lambda$, we can choose a $v(\lambda)$. But can we get a mapping $\lambda \mapsto v(\lambda)$ that is continuous?

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1200023/continuity-of-the-basis-of-the-null-space?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) seems like a step in the right direction.  Hope that helps